# key-value pair undefined in javascript

Tags: javascript, undefined, key-value

For some reason I have a string like this:

```
"id: 123, title: something, category: science, ... "
```

To make a javascript object containing the key-value pairs I wrote the following method:

```
function stringToMap(stringToCut){
    var map = {};
    var listOfPairs = stringToCut.split(",");
    for(var i = 0; i < listOfPairs.length; i++){
        var pair = listOfPairs[i].split(":");
        map[pair[0]] = pair[1];
    }

    return map;
```

}

it's important to access it with dot, not with [] brackets.
In chrome debug mode I see the expected object, but when I want to access one of it's element, like:

```
console.log(obj.title);
```

I get undefined...

What Am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's because there's a space in your key name:

```
console.log(obj[" title"]); // "something"
```

To fix this, change your first split to split on `", "` instead of just `","`:

```
var listOfPairs = stringToCut.split(", ");
```

[**JSFiddle demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/JamesD/xG3Td/2/).

As a further fix, you'll also want to change your second split to split on `": "` rather than just `":"`, otherwise all your values will begin with spaces.

```
var pair = listOfPairs[i].split(": ");
```

Comment: Mind the space in the beginning. `console.log(obj["title"].trim());`

Comment: Indeed, that space was the problem. Thanks a lot!